# Multi-mixin helper leads to unexpected non-assignable compiler error. Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type a multi-mixin helper function that accepts a map of constructors and returns a map of those constructors extended with some new interface.

Consider the following contrived base classes:

```
class Alpha { alpha: string = 'alpha'; };
class Beta { beta: string = 'beta'; };
```

I have a mixin helper function that accepts a map of these classes and returns optionally extended versions of them. Without typings, it looks like this:

```
// The multi-mixin helper function:
const Fooable = ({ Alpha, Beta }) => {
  const AlphaWithFoo = class extends Alpha {
    foo = 'foo';
  };

  return { Alpha: AlphaWithFoo, Beta };
}

// When invoked, it might be used like this:
const { Alpha: FooAlpha, Beta: FooBeta } = Fooable({ Alpha, Beta });
const fooAlpha = new FooAlpha();

// fooAlpha has both "alpha" and "foo" propoerties:
console.log(fooAlpha.alpha, fooAlpha.foo);
```

However, when I fully type this helper function out, my typings lead to a very strange not-assignable compiler error. Here is a link to the TypeScript compiler playground where you can see the typings I'm using, and the associated error:

## **[live example in typescriptlang.org playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F**%0D%0A%20*%20Contrived%20base%20classes...%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0Aclass%20Alpha%20%7B%20alpha%3A%20string%20%3D%20'alpha'%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aclass%20Beta%20%7B%20beta%3A%20string%20%3D%20'beta'%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F**%0D%0A%20*%20Core%20types...%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0Atype%20Constructor%3CT%3D%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Mixin%3CS%2C%20M%3E%20%3D%20(SuperClass%3A%20Constructor%3CS%3E)%20%3D%3E%20Constructor%3CM%20%26%20S%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Domain%3CA%20extends%20Alpha%2C%20B%20extends%20Beta%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Alpha%3A%20Constructor%3CA%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Beta%3A%20Constructor%3CB%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ExtendedDomain%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CA%20extends%20Alpha%2C%20B%20extends%20Beta%2C%20MA%20%3D%20%7B%7D%2C%20MB%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20extends%20Domain%3CAlpha%2C%20Beta%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Alpha%3A%20Constructor%3CA%20%26%20MA%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Beta%3A%20Constructor%3CB%20%26%20MB%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20DomainExtender%3CMA%2C%20MB%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CA%20extends%20Alpha%2C%20B%20extends%20Beta%3E(%7B%20Alpha%2C%20Beta%20%7D%3A%20Domain%3CA%2C%20B%3E)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ExtendedDomain%3CA%2C%20B%2C%20MA%2C%20MB%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F**%0D%0A%20*%20Test%20the%20types...%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0Aconst%20BaseDomain%3A%20Domain%3CAlpha%2C%20Beta%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20Alpha%2C%20Beta%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Everything%20seems%20fine%20for%20a%20basic%20mixin%20usage%3A%0D%0Aconst%20WithFoo%3A%20Mixin%3CAlpha%2C%20Foo%3E%20%3D%20SuperClass%20%3D%3E%20class%20extends%20SuperClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%20%3D%20'foo'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20AlphaWithFoo%20%3D%20WithFoo(Alpha)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20alphaWithFoo%20%3D%20new%20AlphaWithFoo()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(alphaWithFoo.alpha)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(alphaWithFoo.foo)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20FooDomain%3A%20ExtendedDomain%3CAlpha%2C%20Beta%2C%20Foo%2C%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Alpha%3A%20AlphaWithFoo%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Beta%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Compiler%20seems%20to%20get%20confused%20when%20I%20implement%20a%20multi-mixin%0D%0A%2F%2F%20function..%20help!%0D%0Aconst%20Fooable%3A%20DomainExtender%3CFoo%2C%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20(%7B%20Alpha%2C%20Beta%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20a%20%3D%20new%20Alpha()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20AlphaWithFoo%20%3D%20class%20extends%20Alpha%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%20%3D%20'foo'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20Alpha%3A%20AlphaWithFoo%2C%20Beta%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Strangely%2C%20Fooable%20seems%20to%20return%20constructors%20with%20the%20correct%20types%20(hover%0D%0A%2F%2F%20text%20shows%20the%20correct%20type%20information).%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20Alpha%3A%20FooableAlpha%2C%20Beta%3A%20FooableBeta%20%7D%20%3D%20Fooable(%7B%20Alpha%2C%20Beta%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fooableAlpha%20%3D%20new%20FooableAlpha()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20fooableBeta%20%3D%20new%20FooableBeta()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(fooableAlpha.foo%2C%20fooableAlpha.alpha)%3B%0D%0A)**

The error I'm getting reads:

```
Type '<A extends Alpha, B extends Beta>({ Alpha, Beta }: Domain<A, B>) => { Alpha: typeof AlphaWithFoo;...' is not assignable to type 'DomainExtender<Foo, {}>'.
  Type '{ Alpha: typeof AlphaWithFoo; Beta: Constructor<B>; }' is not assignable to type 'ExtendedDomain<A, B, Foo, {}>'.
    Types of property 'Alpha' are incompatible.
      Type 'typeof AlphaWithFoo' is not assignable to type 'Constructor<A & Foo>'.
        Type 'AlphaWithFoo' is not assignable to type 'A & Foo'.
```

This error seems kind of strange to me. It is as though the compiler is losing track of the type information for the `Alpha` class or something. But, it is probably more likely that I am making a mistake somewhere.

Can anyone help me figure out where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quirk in the way you can derive from a generic parameter, the generic parameter must extend  `new(...args: any[]) => any` (parameters MUST be `...args: any[]`). We can see this in action in this [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743). To get around this we can use a helper function inside the `Fooable` function:

```
const Fooable: DomainExtender<Foo, {}> = ({ Alpha, Beta }) => {
    function mixin<U extends Constructor>(Base: U) {
        return class extends Base {
            constructor(...args: any[]) {
                super(...args);
            }
            foo: string = 'foo';
        }
    }
    const AlphaWithFoo = mixin(Alpha);

    return { Alpha: AlphaWithFoo, Beta };
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to specify the appropriate constructor without the `mixin` helper? e.g,: https://gist.github.com/cdata/d2e4a544586c5386087bb28eeb51fcef

Comment: @cdata I agree you should, but I have found this feature to be very particular about how you define the constraint. But this works without any extra casting and it preserves types

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This at least gives me a tolerable work-around, but I have to admit that this behavior seems quirky enough to be considered a bug. The `mixin` helper you suggested seems like nothing more than an arbitrary indirection.

Comment: @cdata I fully agree with you it makes no sense for one to be allowed but not the other. I have not had time to search for a similar bug and file a report if it does not exist (I am not associated in any way with the TS team)