# Why method added through decoration is not accessible

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose that I have a Directive decorator which adds a static method to it's target called factory:

```
function Directive<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
  return class extends constructor {
    static factory(...args): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
      const c: any = () => {
        return constructor.apply(this, args);
      };
      c.prototype = constructor.prototype;
      return new c(...args);
    }
  };
}
```

I also add the type via an interface:

```
interface BaseDirective extends ng.IDirective {
  factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory;
}
```

Why in my class declaration of:

```
@Directive
class FocusedDirective implements BaseDirective {....
```

I get a `Class 'FocusedDirective' incorrectly implements interface 'BaseDirective'.
  Property 'factory' is missing in type 'FocusedDirective'.`

Am I wrong to expect from `@Directive` to add this missing property for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators can't change the type of the class, you can invoke your decorator as a function and store the new class which will contain the method and use the new class instead of the original:

```
 const FocusedDirectiveWithDirective = Directive(FocusedDirective);
```

You can do away with the intermediate class altogether  by using class expressions:

```
const FocusedDirective = Directive(class implements BaseDirective{

});
```

Comment: sounds like a serious limitation of TypeScript, do you know if the behavior of typescript decorators may change when the ecmascript standard settles?

Comment: @TamasHegedus Limitation, design decision up for debate. but it's not hard to get around it. I am not aware of any plans to change this  behaviour, but I have not been following the conversation so I could not say

Comment: @TamasHegedus added a version without the intermediate class, if you squint it almost looks like a decorator :)

Comment: Yeah, not the most ideal situation to have to wrap it like that. The other issue we have is accessing constructor arguments inside a decorator in strict mode is now allowed. 
I think the whole thing needs a little more work to be useful properly.

Comment: @XGreen yeah, this whole mixin thing seems to have strange bugs, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846830/multi-mixin-helper-leads-to-unexpected-non-assignable-compiler-error-am-i-doing/49010608#49010608

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.  The first has little to do with decorators: `factory` is a static method in your implementation, but a regular method in your interface:

```
interface BaseDirective  {
    factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory;
}
```

That's going to be a problem for you.  For now I'm going to convert the implementation to a regular method, since it's simpler to implement.

```
function Directive<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
    return class extends constructor {
        factory(...args: any[]): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
            const c: any = () => {
                return constructor.apply(this, args);
            };
            c.prototype = constructor.prototype;
            return new c(...args);
        }
    };
}
```

---

The second issue: decorators do not mutate the class signature the way you're expecting.  This is an [oft-requested feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) and there are some interesting issues around why it's not a simple problem to solve.  Importantly, it's not easy to figure out how to support having the implementation of the class refer to the mutated type.  In your case: would the stuff inside your `{....` know about `factory()` or not?  Most people seem to expect it would, but the decorator hasn't been applied yet.

The workaround is not to use decorator syntax at all, but instead to use the decorator function as a regular function to create a new class.  The syntax looks like this:

```
class FocusedDirective extends Directive(class {

    // any impl that doesn't rely on factory
    prop: string = "hey";
    foo() {
        this.prop; // okay
        // this.factory(); // not okay
    }

}) implements BaseDirective {

    // any impl that relies on factory
    bar() {
        this.prop; // okay
        this.foo(); // okay
        this.factory(); // okay
    }

}
```

This also solves the "does the implementation know about the decorator" issue, since the stuff inside the decorator function does not, and the stuff outside does, as you see above.

---

Back to the static/instance issue.  If you want to enforce a constraint on the static side of a class, you can't do it by having the class implement anything.  Instead, you need to enforce the static side on the class constructor itself. Like this:

```
interface BaseDirective {
  // any actual instance stuff here
}

interface BaseDirectiveConstructor {
    new(...args: any[]): BaseDirective;
    factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory;
}

class FocusedDirective extends Directive(class {
   // impl without BaseDirectiveConstructor
}) implements BaseDirective {
    // impl with BaseDirectiveConstructor
    bar() {
        FocusedDirective.factory(); // okay
    }
}

function ensureBaseDirectiveConstructor<T extends BaseDirectiveConstructor>(t: T): void {}
ensureBaseDirectiveConstructor(FocusedDirective);
```

The `ensureBaseDirectiveConstructor()` function makes sure that the `FocusedDirective` class constructor has a static `factory()` method of the right type.  That's where you'd see an error if you failed to implement the static side.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck.